# How to configure client certificates in Jetty + Spring

Tags: spring, ssl, jetty, client-certificates

We are using a Jetty server along with Spring security framework. The server should accept requests from only from a known client (Which is also a server). We want to configure client certificates so that Jetty accepts only the requests with the known client certificate.

How can we configure the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we need to do is set ***NeedClientAuth*** in jetty-ssl-config.xml to **true**. No change is needed in Spring config.